# prop() and attr() not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

[developed by someone else] Working on a bug. Initially, the month picker input field will be disabled until you enter a value on the left side input. It works in Chrome and other browsers, but not in IE11.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <h5 class="control-label subaccount-view" data-bind="text: ProfileViewModel.userProfile().GATarget"></h5>
    <input type="text" id="txtGATarget" class="subaccount-edit txt-gatarget txt-contolrs cls-validate-txt" style="display:none">
    <span class="text-danger" id="gaTargetVal" style="display:none">@T("subaccount-emptygatarget")</span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 cls-addinfo-history">
    <div class="input-dp-wrap">
    <input type="text" class="month_year" id="effectiveDateFrom_GA" disabled="disabled" />
    <span class="text-danger" id="ga_DateVal" style="display:none">@T("subaccount-month-invalidselect")</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS -

```
$('.txt-gatarget').change(function () {
    var gatarget = $(this).val();
    $('#gaTargetVal').css("display", "none");
    if (gatarget == "") {
        var errMsg = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(T("subaccount-emptygatarget")));
        $('#gaTargetVal').html(errMsg.Text) ;
        $('#gaTargetVal').css("display", "block");
        $('#submitAdditionalInfo').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.btn-saveedit').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else if(gatarget.indexOf(".") >= 0)
    {
        var errMsg = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(T("subaccount-invalidgatarget")));
        $('#gaTargetVal').html(errMsg.Text) ;
        $('#gaTargetVal').css("display", "block");
        $('#submitAdditionalInfo').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.btn-saveedit').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        var isAllowed = EnableButton();
        if(!isAllowed)
        {
            $('#submitAdditionalInfo').attr('disabled', true);
            $('.btn-saveedit').attr('disabled', true);
        }
        $('#effectiveDateFrom_GA').prop('disabled', false)  ;
    }
});
```

The version of jQuery being used is 1.11.0 if you ask.

Comment: Use `prop()`. Now if it is still not working, provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue.

Comment: @A.Wolff - I found out the problem. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. Event was not triggering on `.change`. i used keyup instead. It worked. `$('.txt-gatarget').keyup(function () {`

Comment: @A.Wolff - Check the attached image. Like i said, the month picker input field will be disabled initially until you enter a value on the left side input. Once you enter a value on the left side input, the month picker input will be enabled.

Comment: BUT like i said change event has different behaviour. It is fired once element loses focus, not like keyup event. What if you user pass some value to input using is mouse (context menu)? Your keyup event won't be fired

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the head tag of your page

```
<!--[if IE 8]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```